# How to get the characters / words that lie on both sides, between which our selected character fall?

Tags: javascript, string

Let's consider a string **str** which is defined as :

```
const str = " 'I am going' - 'I' "
```

and a function **calc()** which can be used as :

```
console.log( calc(str) ) // => am going
```

So, I decided to make the **calc()** using regex ! So here is what I thought about.

```
const calc = (str) => {
 const reg = // Not understanding how to get the strings between which '-' falls
 str = str.replace(reg, function(_, a) {
   const b = remove(a[0], a[1])
   return b
 })
 return str
}
```

**remove()** is a function for removing words from string, I made. You can freely modify my code if there is anything incorrect. It's an example how I imagined. So, please help me completing my function !

Comment: What exactly do you want the regex to capture?

Comment: I want my regex go give me an array, arr = ['I am going', 'I'], I have a function named remove(), and I will do this : remove(arr[0], arr[1]) will give me 'am going'

Comment: So you want to remove `I` and the hyphen `-`?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the question.

Comment: It's not my homework, I just wanted to have a new syntax. Javascript can add strings with +, so I imagined the opposite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split the string at `-` and get the content within `''` suing `match`. Then, create a dynamic regex using the [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor and `replace` all the instance of second match from the first match

```js
function calc(str) {
  const [first, second] = str.split(/\s*-\s*/)
                             .map(s => s.match(/'([^']+)'/)[1])

  return first.replace(new RegExp(second, "g"), '')
}

console.log(calc("'I am going' - 'I'"))
console.log(calc("'Remove this from this string' - 'this'"))
```

If [`matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) is supported in your environment, you could also:

```
const [first, second] = Array.from(str.matchAll(/'([^']+)'/g), ([,m]) => m)
```